# Нет источника данных MySQL (WPF)

Tags: mysql, wpf, ado

столкнулся с проблемой, связанной с моделью базы данных ADO NET

Писал программу WPF (.NET Framework 4.7.2, VisualStudio2022), хотел добавить модель базы данных (MySQL на сервере), но не обнаружил в источниках поставщика MySQL

Я пробовал установить MySQL Connector (8.0.33), но ничего не добавилось

Кто знает как добавить, можете поделиться информацией? Заранее спасибо!

[image: Источник данных]